# Pass by value Linked list

Tags: java, linked-list

I am trying to rearrange a Singly linked list. The initial list will be 1,2,3,4,5
and they have to be sorted in 1,5,2,4,3. I have the code and I am trying to understand how it works. Basically I am stuck at the concept of pass by value in java.

The complete code

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    LinkedLists linkedList = new LinkedLists();
    linkedList.append(1);
    linkedList.append(2);
    linkedList.append(3);
    linkedList.append(4);
    linkedList.append(5);
    linkedList.reorderList();

}}

class Node {
int data;
Node next;

public Node(int data) {
    this.data = data;
}}
```

class LinkedLists {

```
Node head;

public void reorderList() {
    if (head == null) {
        System.out.println(head);
        return;
    }
    Node slowPointer = head;
    Node fastPointer = head.next;
    System.out.println(slowPointer.hashCode());
    System.out.println(head.hashCode());
    while (fastPointer != null && fastPointer.next != null) {
        fastPointer = fastPointer.next.next;
        slowPointer = slowPointer.next;// why head value did not change
    }

    Node head2 = slowPointer.next;
    slowPointer.next = null;// why did the head value change here
    LinkedList<Node> queue = new LinkedList<Node>();
    while (head2 != null) {
        Node temp = head2;
        head2 = head2.next;
        temp.next = null;
        queue.push(temp);
    }
    while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
        Node temp = queue.pop();
        temp.next = head.next;
        head.next = temp;
        head = temp.next;
    }

}

public void append(int data) {
    if (head == null) {
        head = new Node(data);
        return;
    }
    Node current = head;
    while (current.next != null) {
        current = current.next;
    }
    current.next = new Node(data);
}}
```

The value of head does not get changed at line

```
slowPointer = slowPointer.next;// why head value did not change
```

But at line

```
slowPointer.next = null;// why did the head value change here
```

Why does it change here. Thanks.

Comment: `slowPointer = slowPointer.next;` is assigning a new value to a variable.
`slowPointer.next = null;` is modifying the state of an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because in the first case you are assigning the object pointed by next to the slowPointer.

But in second case you are modifying the value of 'next' of the object being pointed by the reference slowPointer. So the head object is directly modified.

Comment: Could you please explain a little more in detail. I still have a little difficulty in understanding it.

Comment: slowPointer is actually a reference. It just points to a Node object. When an assignment ie, = is done it changes the object it is pointing to. But when '.' is used, it accesses the attribute of the Node object of its currently pointing to and any operation changes the actual cake in that object.